# Using Nexmo with c++

Tags: c++, sms, vonage

I am trying to send an sms with nexmo.

What I am doing is: I have a video of cars, when a car of wanted license passes, I will send an SMS to person x.

My code is in c++.. Can Nexmo be used with c++?
I find documentations for c# only

Answer (score 1):

There is no C++ SDK for Nexmo, so you need to resort doing your API calls directly. This shouldn't be too hard and you can leverage libcurl or any other HTTP library. This is the way our company does API calls from C/C++ code, though not to Nexmo.

libCURL has plenty examples of how to do it:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

If you want some nice C++ wrapper over libcurl you can find one here (I'm sure you can find more):
https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp

In any case you can always join Nexmo Community Slack and raise the question about creating C++ SDK.
https://developer.nexmo.com/community/slack